# How do I capture command+number hotkeys in Safari with jQuery

Tags: jquery, safari, hotkeys

I am trying to capture the Command+1 hotkey on a mac using Safari.  As of now my code works in firefox, but Safari still loads the bookmark associated with that number.  I have read that Safari doesn't let you capture DOM objects, but I'm not sure where to go from here.  Right now I am using

```
$(document)
    .bind('keypress', 'Command+1', function(){
    //load popup
    alert("Hello World.");
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should help you get the right direction:

```
$(document).bind('keypress', function(event){
    console.log(event);
    if(event.ctrlKey || event.cmdKey){
       console.log(event.keyCode+"+command");
    }
});
```

in firefox on a mac the command key sends a different key code instead of sending a double key trigger. So the lowercase letter x = 88, and lowercase x holding command = 224. So you may just have to apply some math to figure out if the command key was held.